# Framer Motion - How can I stop animation propagating to child elements of div?

Tags: reactjs, animation, framer-motion

I have a few modals that pop up with framer motion animations like this.

The black background fades in.

```
<motion.div
      initial={{
        opacity: 0,
      }}
      animate={{
        opacity: 1,
      }}
      transition={{
        ease: "easeIn",
        duration: 0.2,
      }}
      
    >
```

The popup box appears at scale 1, expands to scale 1.2 and then shrinks back down to the final size, scale 1.

```
<motion.div
        initial={{
          scale: 0,
        }}
        animate={{
          scale: [1, 1.2, 1],
        }}
        transition={{
          ease: "easeOut",
          duration: 0.6,
        }}
        
      >
```

I want it to be so that only the div box expands and not the text, images, any content. All child elements of the div need to remain at scale 1 throughout the animation.

Is there a way to stop the animation propagating to child elements?

I've wrapping the contents in a `<motion.div>` and setting it as below:

```
<motion.div
          initial={{
            scale: 1,
          }}
          animate={{
            scale: [1, 1, 1],
          }}
        >
```

Here is the important stuff:
https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-wilson-93xnfq?file=/src/App.js

Any help, greatly appreciated!